# commandLink inside datatable redirect to servlet only work for first time click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFace 4.0. There is a datatable which list some documents of the login user. When user click on one row of datatable, it will open a new page and display PDF content of the document. It works for the 1st click, after 1st click on the same original page (which list documents) clicking on any element will open a new window but it navigate to the home page.
The datatable looks like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="tableLicenseeDocuments" value="#{pc_LicenseeDocumentsBean.documentList}" var="document">                       

<p:column sortBy="documentName" headerText="#{bundle['header.name']}"  >
    <h:commandLink value="#{document.documentName}"  action="#{documentsBean.viewFile(document)}" ajax="false" target="_blank"/>
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

The DocumentBean is in session scope, the action viewFile looks like this:

```
public void viewFile(DocumentDto document)  {
    FacesContext faceContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext extContext = faceContext.getExternalContext();
    PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) extContext.getRequest();
    PortletSession pSession = portletRequest.getPortletSession(true);
    pSession.setAttribute("document", document , PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
    String baseUrl = extContext.getRequestContextPath();
    String url = baseUrl + "/DisplayPDFServlet";
    try {
        String encodeURL = extContext.encodeRedirectURL(url, null);
        extContext.redirect(encodeURL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // Handle the exception here ...
    } finally {
         faceContext.responseComplete();
    }
```

The page includes datatable is loaded by user click on side menu, which is also commandLink, going to back bean to load the data, then display, the lifecycle of the displaying the page is: (please note after phase 5, there is an extra phase 1 RESOTRE_VIEW, why there is an extra RESOTRE_VIEW phase here, is the view already restored?)

> > 1.START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
> >
> > 2.END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
> >
> > 3.START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(2)
> >
> > 4.END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(2)
> >
> > 5.START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3)
> >
> > 6.END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3)
> >
> > 7.START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(4)
> >
> > 8.END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(4)
> >
> > 9.START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION(5)
> >
> > 10.END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION(5)
> >
> > **11.START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)**
> >
> > **12.END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)**
> >
> > 13.START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
> >
> > 14.END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

When user 1st time click on the row of the datatable, which open a new window and display the content, the life cycle is like following:

> > 1.START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
> >
> > 2.END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
> >
> > 3.START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(2)
> >
> > 4.END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(2)
> >
> > 5.START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3)
> >
> > 6.END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3)
> >
> > 7.START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(4)
> >
> > 8.END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(4)
> >
> > 9.START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION(5)
> >
> > 10.END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION(5)

On the same page has the datatable, when user 2nd click on the row, it actually goes to home page:

> > 1.START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
> >
> > 2.END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
> >
> > 3.START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
> >
> > 4.END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

It's actually a Portlet, but I think the problem is JSF-related. I've been struggle on it for couple days, any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried return url instead of redirect in the method? Like:
`public String viewFile(...`

Comment: Yes I did. Originally it was returned with outcome string like you suggested, later I removed it, there are no difference in both ways.